# How to update Seller Order Id with Amazon SP API

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I have been trying to update Seller Order ID with SP API Feeds API. But it is getting updated on sellercentral.

Bellow is my XML Feed Document:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>123456789</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Order</MessageType>
<PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Order>
        <SellerOrderId>56789</SellerOrderId>
        <StandardOrderID>
            <Type>AmazonOrderId</Type>
            <Value>123-1234567-1234567</Value>
        </StandardOrderID>
    </Order>
</Message>
```

Answer (score 1):

All the xml schemas can be found here.

[Amazon SP API feeds](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feed-type-values#order-feeds)

Comment: did you manage to do this?

Comment: yes, I created an xml following the schemas on the above mentioned link. and it updated the info in seller central.

Comment: Can you please paste the code to manage this? I want to update SellerOrderId too, but this answer does not help too much. Thank you